# How to define Intent for call other applications?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I got a simple widget that's show a label with text.
What I'm trying to do is give the chance to send this text via sms, mail, tweet it or set it as state message in gtalk.

How should i build my Intents objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to give the user a choice of all apps that 'share'  twitter, email, etc use this

```
    public static void launchNewShareIntent(Context c, String subject, String text, String dialogTitle){
       Intent shareintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       shareintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
       shareintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
       shareintent.setType("text/plain");
       shareintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       c.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareintent, dialogTitle));
}
```